# Помогите усовершенствовать раскрывающееся дерево

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul li a').click(function () {
            $('.select').removeClass('select');
            $(this).addClass('select');
        });
    });
function tree(target) {
        var ul = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0);
        ul.style.display = (ul.style.display == "block")? "none": "block";
    }
```

```css
.listCategory {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul {
     list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
 }
li.fullList
{
    /*list-style-image: url("../img/arrow_full_blue_right.png");*/
    list-style-position: outside;
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
li.nullList {
    /*list-style-image: url("../img/arrow_null_right.png");*/
    list-style-position: outside;
}
li a:active, li a:focus, .select  {
    background-color: gainsboro;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.select {
    background-color: gainsboro;
}
a, .listSub2Item, div .arr
{
    background-color: white;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.SubItem:before {
    border-left: 1px dotted grey;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.listCategory:before {
    border-left: 1px dotted grey;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.listCategory li {
    position: relative;
}
.listCategory li::before {
    border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
.listCategory li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;
    left: 0;
}
li.Node {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
li{
    padding-left: 1em;
    border: 1px dotted grey;
    border-width:  0 0 1px 1px;
}
li ul {
   /* border-top: 0 dotted black;*/
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}
ul { padding-left: 1em; }
li { padding-left: 1em;
   /* border: 1px dotted black;*/
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
li a {
    position: relative;
    top: 0.6em;
}
ul li:last-child ul {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    margin-left: -17px;
}
.listSubItem {
    background: white;
}
.arr {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.SubItem {
    border-left: 1px dotted grey!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="treeCategory">
   <ul class="listCategory">
        <li class="Node item fullList"><a  class="arr" onclick="tree(this)">►</a><a class="" onclick="tree(this)">Пункт 1</a>
            <ul class="listSubItem" style="display: none">
                <li class="Node SubItem nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 1.1</a></li>
                <li class="Node SubItem fullList"><a class="arr" onclick="tree(this)">►</a><a class="" onclick="tree(this)">Пункт 1.2</a>
                    <ul class="listSub2Item" style="display: none">
                        <li class="Node Sub2Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 1.2.1</a></li>
                        <li class="Node Sub2Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 1.2.2</a></li>
                        <li class="Node Sub2Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 1.2.3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="Node item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 2</a></li>
        <li class="Node item fullList"><a class="arr"onclick="tree(this)">►</a><a class="" onclick="tree(this)">Пункт 3</a>
            <ul class="listSubItem" style="display: none">
                <li class="Node SubItem nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.1</a></li>
                <li class="Node SubItem nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.2</a></li>
                <li class="Node SubItem fullList"><a class="arr" onclick="tree(this)">►</a><a class="" onclick="tree(this)">Пункт 3.3</a>
                    <ul class="listSub2Item" style="display: none">
                        <li class="Node Sub2Item fullList"><a class="arr" onclick="tree(this)">►</a><a class="" onclick="tree(this)">Пункт 3.3.1</a>
                            <ul class="listSub3bItem" style="display: none">
                                <li class="Node Sub3Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.3.1.1</a></li>
                                <li class="Node Sub3Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.3.1.2</a></li>
                                <li class="Node Sub3Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.3.1.3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="Node Sub2Item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 3.3.2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="Node item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 4</a></li>
        <li class="Node item nullList"><a class="arr">►</a><a class="">Пункт 5</a></li>

    </ul>


</div>
```

*задача у меня такая Необходимо реализовать дерево средствами JS(native)+HTML+CSS3. Базовый принцип работы идентичен навигации по каталогам в проводнике Windows:

у каждого узла, у которого есть дети, должна быть отдельная иконка-стрелочка с возможностью скрыть/развернуть его. Если детей нет, иконки для сворачивания быть не должно;
количество уровней вложенности неограниченно;
при клике, элемент должен подсвечиваться;
Источником данных выступает json-структура следующего вида:

{data:[

```
            {itemId:1, itemName:"пункт №1", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:2, itemName:"пункт №1.1", itemParentId:1},

            {itemId:3, itemName:"пункт №1.2", itemParentId:1},

            {itemId:4, itemName:"пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:5, itemName:"пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:6, itemName:"пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId:3},

            {itemId:7, itemName:"пункт №2", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:8, itemName:"пункт №3", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:9, itemName:"пункт №3.1", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:10, itemName:"пункт №3.2", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:11, itemName:"пункт №3.3", itemParentId:8},

            {itemId:12, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId:11},

            {itemId:13, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:14, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:15, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId:12},

            {itemId:16, itemName:"пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId:11},

            {itemId:17, itemName:"пункт №4", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:18, itemName:"пункт №5", itemParentId:0},

            {itemId:19, itemName:"пункт №5.1", itemParentId:18}
```

]}*

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить пару моментов. 1) Структура данных именно такая или её можно поменять? 2) Пункты меню отсортированы как у вас в примере или могут быть в случайном порядке?

Comment: Структура данных именно такая, и пункты меню строятся из структуры json данных

Comment: 2) Пункты меню отсортированы как у вас в примере или могут быть в случайном порядке?

Comment: как указано в примере, я строил дерево на основе json данных, теперь я хочу чтобы данные уже подгружались и строилось  дерево, на основе этих данных

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexeyLem/mj8usgbd/

Принцип работы думаю будет понятен, а разукрасите уже сами ...

```js
var data = [
    {itemId:1, itemName:"пункт №1", itemParentId:0},
    {itemId:2, itemName:"пункт №1.1", itemParentId:1},
    {itemId:3, itemName:"пункт №1.2", itemParentId:1},
    {itemId:4, itemName:"пункт №1.2.1", itemParentId:3},
    {itemId:5, itemName:"пункт №1.2.2", itemParentId:3},
    {itemId:6, itemName:"пункт №1.2.3", itemParentId:3},
    {itemId:7, itemName:"пункт №2", itemParentId:0},
    {itemId:8, itemName:"пункт №3", itemParentId:0},
    {itemId:9, itemName:"пункт №3.1", itemParentId:8},
    {itemId:10, itemName:"пункт №3.2", itemParentId:8},
    {itemId:11, itemName:"пункт №3.3", itemParentId:8},
    {itemId:12, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1", itemParentId:11},
    {itemId:13, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.1", itemParentId:12},
    {itemId:14, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.2", itemParentId:12},
    {itemId:15, itemName:"пункт №3.3.1.3", itemParentId:12},
    {itemId:16, itemName:"пункт №3.3.2", itemParentId:11},
    {itemId:17, itemName:"пункт №4", itemParentId:0},
    {itemId:18, itemName:"пункт №5", itemParentId:0},
    {itemId:19, itemName:"пункт №5.1", itemParentId:18}
];

var checkList = {};

function getChild(list, id) {
    return list.filter(function(item) {
     return item.itemParentId == id;
    });
}

function doTree(list) {

    var html = '';
    
    list.forEach(function(item, index) {

     var chld;

        if(typeof checkList[item.itemId] != 'undefined') return ;

        if(chld = getChild(list, item.itemId)) {
            html += ('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">'+item.itemName+'</a><ul>'+doTree(chld)+'</ul></li>');
        }else{
            html += ('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">'+item.itemName+'</a></li>');
        }

        checkList[item.itemId]=true;
    });
    
    return html;
}

$('#root').html(doTree(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="root"></ul>
```

ЗЫ: Структура данных не очень подходит для хранения дерева ...

Answer (score 0):

Разукрасил :)

```js
var CreateDom = function(json) {
  var elList = document.getElementById('list');
  var hierarchy = [];

  for (var i in json.data) {
    var it = json.data[i];

    var el = document.createElement('li');
    el.innerHTML = '<a class="">' + it.itemName + '</a>';

    if (it.itemParentId == 0) {
      el.className = 'Node item nullList';
      hierarchy[it.itemId] = {
        el: el,
        sup: 1
      };
      elList.appendChild(el);
    } else {
      var parent = hierarchy[it.itemParentId].el;

      if (parent.children.length == 1) {
        parent.children[0].setAttribute('onclick', 'tree(this);');

        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.style.display = 'none';
        if (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup == 1) {
          parent.className = 'Node item fullList';
          ul.className = 'listSubItem';
        } else {
          if (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup == 2) {
            parent.className = 'Node SubItem fullList';
          } else {
            parent.className = 'Node Sub' + (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup - 1) + 'Item fullList';
          }
          ul.className = 'listSub' + (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup + 1) + 'Item';
        }
        parent.appendChild(ul);

        var _a = document.createElement('a');
        _a.className = 'arr';
        _a.setAttribute('onclick', 'tree(this);');
        _a.innerHTML = '►';
        parent.insertBefore(_a, parent.firstChild);
      }

      if (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup == 2) {
        el.className = 'Node SubItem nullList';
      } else {
        el.className = 'Node Sub' + (hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup - 1) + 'Item nullList';
      }

      hierarchy[it.itemId] = {
        el: el,
        sup: hierarchy[it.itemParentId].sup + 1
      };
      parent.lastChild.appendChild(el);

    }

  }
};

var _json = {
  data: [{
    itemId: 1,
    itemName: "пункт №1",
    itemParentId: 0
  }, {
    itemId: 2,
    itemName: "пункт №1.1",
    itemParentId: 1
  }, {
    itemId: 3,
    itemName: "пункт №1.2",
    itemParentId: 1
  }, {
    itemId: 4,
    itemName: "пункт №1.2.1",
    itemParentId: 3
  }, {
    itemId: 5,
    itemName: "пункт №1.2.2",
    itemParentId: 3
  }, {
    itemId: 6,
    itemName: "пункт №1.2.3",
    itemParentId: 3
  }, {
    itemId: 7,
    itemName: "пункт №2",
    itemParentId: 0
  }, {
    itemId: 8,
    itemName: "пункт №3",
    itemParentId: 0
  }, {
    itemId: 9,
    itemName: "пункт №3.1",
    itemParentId: 8
  }, {
    itemId: 10,
    itemName: "пункт №3.2",
    itemParentId: 8
  }, {
    itemId: 11,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3",
    itemParentId: 8
  }, {
    itemId: 12,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3.1",
    itemParentId: 11
  }, {
    itemId: 13,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.1",
    itemParentId: 12
  }, {
    itemId: 14,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.2",
    itemParentId: 12
  }, {
    itemId: 15,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3.1.3",
    itemParentId: 12
  }, {
    itemId: 16,
    itemName: "пункт №3.3.2",
    itemParentId: 11
  }, {
    itemId: 17,
    itemName: "пункт №4",
    itemParentId: 0
  }, {
    itemId: 18,
    itemName: "пункт №5",
    itemParentId: 0
  }, {
    itemId: 19,
    itemName: "пункт №5.1",
    itemParentId: 18
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.select').removeClass('select');
    $(this).addClass('select');
  });

  CreateDom(_json);
});

function tree(target) {
  var ul = target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0);
  ul.style.display = (ul.style.display == "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
.listCategory {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}
li.fullList {
  /*list-style-image: url("../img/arrow_full_blue_right.png");*/
  list-style-position: outside;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
li.nullList {
  /*list-style-image: url("../img/arrow_null_right.png");*/
  list-style-position: outside;
}
li a:active,
li a:focus,
.select {
  background-color: gainsboro;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a.select {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}
a,
.listSub2Item,
div .arr {
  background-color: white;
}
a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
.SubItem:before {
  border-left: 1px dotted grey;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.listCategory:before {
  border-left: 1px dotted grey;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.listCategory li {
  position: relative;
}
.listCategory li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
.listCategory li:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
}
li.Node {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
li ul {
  /* border-top: 0 dotted black;*/
  margin-left: -1em;
  padding-left: 2em;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  /* border: 1px dotted black;*/
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
li a {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.6em;
}
ul li:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
.listSubItem {
  background: white;
}
.arr {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.SubItem {
  border-left: 1px dotted grey!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="treeCategory">
  <ul id="list" class="listCategory">
  </ul>
</div>
```